# He is hiding a big smile

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

> My name is red and I like dragons
>     though Charizard ain't among my companions;
>     Sometimes I wish I could think before I speak
>     my purity and ingenuity are what make me weak;
>     I even met the lighting god
>     but sadly it was just a fraud;
>     I also have a brother, far bigger than me
>     lucky him, you see,for he is complete;
>     I always befriend all of the creatures
>     doesn't matter how hideous;
>     For one I took the blame and had lotta trouble
>     all 'cause of a guy, man was he subtle!

Who am *I*?

Comment: Please use the 'knowledge', 'movies' and/or 'trivia' tags if necessary. It would be a waste of time if I had to know about a certain tv-show, religion or game to be able to answer this puzzle without a fair warning.

Comment: ops my mistake, you are right

Comment: This sounds like Zorua from Pokemon but the name "red" doesn't make sense unless it is capitalized...is it supposed to be capitalized??

Comment: Maybe this needs a bit more clarification: since red it's stricty related to pokemon, i made the second line to lightly suggest that is no one from the pokemon universe (beacause the bit about dragons it's essential and i couldn't omit it). Yet 'red' is meant to be in lower caps and it's still heavily related to the name of person we are looking for

Comment: i'm sorry if i couldn't be any clearer, my english is not the best. I hope the clarification was helpful and understandable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I read this I think of

> Rubeus Hagrid

I am however not too familiar with all the required background, so please excuse if I cannot provide line by line answers to all the individual hints. But since no one took a shot at this so far, I dare to post this guesswork as a try.

I'll post what few I can match:

Hiding a big smile

> is the demeanor he is typically described with.

red

> "Rubeus" in this pseudo pig latin style of that story line certainly looks reddish to me. The latin word would be *rubinus*. "Rubeus" is supposed to mean red and to be related to alchemy, especially in contrast with the *white* Albus Dumbledore.

fond of dragons

> he hatched his own dragon from an egg, called it Norbert

though Charizard ain't among my companions;

> Yep, it's Hogwarts, not Pokemon

Sometimes I wish I could think before I speak

> He gets into many of his troubles by trustingly talking first and later finding out that he shouldn't have.

my purity and ingenuity are what make me weak;

> This one doesn't fit at all to me. As far as I recall, he is not pure, but a half-breed, causing much discomfort from both sides, and I do not recall him ever being accused of being too ingenious.

lighting god, fraud;

> Also no clue. The fraud that comes in mind was Quirinius Quirrel in disguise, but I have no connection to him being a lighting god (or, if that's a typo, a lightning god) - OP cleared this one up to be lost in translation. It's supposed to be Fluffy, which is named Thor in OP's translation, his big, menacingly looking dog, who is a frightened Wiener by heart (that's the fraud).

a brother, far bigger than me, lucky him, you see, for he is complete;

> could be Grawp, although this is only his half-brother, to be precise, but he is a full pure-bread giant, so far bigger and in this sense complete in a way Hagrid isn't.

I always befriend all of the creatures doesn't matter how hideous;

> That's what he does all the time, Buckbeak, Aragog, Thestrals, etc.
>  He's also professor for the Care of Magical Creatures, and he gives his courses with passion.

For one I took the blame and had lotta trouble

> If the "one" is referring back to creatures, I'm guessing Buckbeak here. Hagrid tried to take all the blame for Buckbeak's actions to save him.

all 'cause of a guy, man was he subtle!

> well, that should be the death-blow to my guess. Nothing in or near Harry Potter is even remotely subtle. Guess I was wrong all along. 
>  OK, besides my ranting, this could be Draco Malfoy (the one dragon hagrid is not fond of), who basically tried to exploit the Buckbeak situation to get Hagrid expelled, and he was going at it as subtle as they come in this story. 
>  Or, if this does not refer to taking the blame, this could be Harry Potter himself, as Hagrid was sworn to protect Harry and got into many a trouble for that. Although I wouldn't get the sublte part then.

Comment: The answer is correct, but you misanswered many of the clues. Anyway, you got it right! Congratulations!

Comment: @Midori Could you hint at which clues are answered incorrectly? So we can get a complete answer?

Comment: He didn't get right the bits about: Red; Purity and Ingenuity; Lighting God; For one i took the blame; The subtle guy. I really hope you can find the right answers!

Comment: I just found out you cant get the lightning god part, i'm very sorry: you see, here in my country hagrid's dog's name is Thor, but it is one big coward (so, a real fraud)! Since Thor isn't really in my country's culture i didn't think they could have changed it's name for geolocalization reasons, i genuinly thought it was its standard name, i'm truly sorry

Comment: @Midori: Oh, cool, i got it? Nice. - Yeah, sorry for the lack of details. I hope it's OK that I presented this incomplete answer. I waited some time, but since no one came up with an answer, I posted my guess. - My guess on red is wrong? Interesting. - Don't bother about Thor, can't double check everything.

Comment: OK, I expanded my answer a bit. But nothing really new. - With "red" I dare to disagree. While you may have something else in mind, I consider my answer to be a solid hit and in consensus with canon. - "Purity and ingenuity"? Yep, not the faintest idea. - "for one I took the blame" I took that to mean "for one of those creatures" from the line above. Is that wrong? - "all cause of a guy" I took that to mean taking that blame because of one guy. Was this assumption correct? - as for "subtle" I stand by my rant that nothing in this fictional background is even remotely subtle, so I have no idea.

Comment: Could the last two lines be about Hagrid getting blamed for opening the chamber of secrets, which got him expelled?

Comment: As for the "Red" piece - what is the last syllable of his name?